# Cannot access AWS EC2 public IP created through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to run one of the first [basic examples](https://github.com/brikis98/terraform-up-and-running-code/blob/master/code/terraform/02-intro-to-terraform-syntax/one-webserver/main.tf) from the book Terraform Up and Running. My `main.tf` is almost identical to the one in the link apart from the version:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami                    = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Hello, World" > index.html
              nohup busybox httpd -f -p 8080 &
              EOF

  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {

  name = var.security_group_name

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

variable "security_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the security group"
  type        = string
  default     = "terraform-example-instance"
}

output "public_ip" {
  value       = aws_instance.example.public_ip
  description = "The public IP of the Instance"
}
```

I ran `terraform apply` and everything seems to be created successfully. However, when I try to run `curl http://<EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_IP>:8080`, the command hangs.

I created my AWS account right before I ran the example, so it uses the default network configuration.

The routing table has an entry pointing to the Internet Gateway of the VPC:

```
Destination    |      Target      |     Status      |   Propagated
0.0.0.0/0      |     igw-<igwId>  |      active     |      No
```

The Network ACLs has the default settings:

```
Rule number   |    Type    | Protocol  | Port range | Source    | Allow/Deny
100           | All traffic|    All    |    All     | 0.0.0.0/0 |    Allow
*             | All traffic|    All    |    All     | 0.0.0.0/0 |    Deny
```

My Terraform version is `v0.14.10`.

Any ideas on how to access the instance's server through the EC2's public IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong the TF program. I **verified** it using my sandbox account and it works as expected. It takes 1-2 minutes for script to start working, so maybe you are testing it too soon.

So whatever difficulties you have are not due to the script itself. So either what you posted on SO is **not your actual code**, or you have somehow **modified** your VPC configurations which make the instance not-accessible.

Comment: This is why I am so confused. I created the AWS specifically for this example and it doesn't work. I copy-pasted the script from my example, so this is the actual code. Do you have an idea how I could try to debug the network configuration?

Comment: Okay, right after I posted my previous comment, I got closer to realising what the problem is. There is some issue when I try to access it from my computer when I am connected to my WiFi network. It works as expected when I access it from my phone using 4G. I am a networking newbie, so any idea on how to check whether there's a problem locally or if there's a reason why AWS doesn't like my IP for some reason?